# Font-size dropdown in CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

I have a query related to the font-size dropdown provided in CKEDITOR.

If I have the below text in my editor,

```
<span style="font-size:16px;">test abbreviations</span>
```

Then on selection, it shows the current font-size in the dropdown.
But I want the font-size to be highlighted not only when the text is within a `<span>` tag, but within a `<p>` tag or any other tag also.

Is this possible?